# Use custom font in React app using typescript and styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a React app from create-react-app I'm using typescript and styled-components

I have a globalStyles

```
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components';

export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'modernline';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url("./fonts/modernline.ttf") format('ttf')
    }
`
```

and I'm using that in the App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {GlobalStyle} from './globalstyle'
// 
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const FontContainer = styled.div`
    font-family: 'modernline';
    font-size: 2em;
    color: red;
`

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <h1>Font Test</h1>
      <FontContainer>
        Custom Font
      </FontContainer> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The cusotm font doesn't show

What do I need to do use a custom font in a create-react-app using typescript and styled-components

Comment: You may be missing a step:  https://dev.to/alaskaa/how-to-import-a-web-font-into-your-react-app-with-styled-components-4-1dni

Comment: I think this is what I have done

Comment: Notice the `import GlobalFonts from './fonts/fonts';` and `<GlobalFonts />` parts.

Answer (score 1):

These fonts are fetched from your local server. The path is "./fonts/modernline.ttf". Check your network request to see if everything works fine.